# Separate and loop string object javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string

How can I loop over this in javascript
`var car = "{"Uber","Lyft"}"`

I would want to loop over every string in car. So Uber and Lyft in this case. The end goal is to convert this to a Json Object so `{text1: Uber, text2: Lyft}`

Answer (score 2):

Replace the first `{` with `[`, the last `}` with `]`, then you can use `JSON.parse()` to get an array that you can loop over.

```js
var car = '{"Uber","Lyft"}';
var json = '[' + car.substr(1, car.length-2) + ']';
var array = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(array);
```